# Solidity - selfdestruct doesnt work!

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, selfdestruct

I implemented `selfdestruct()`, also it showed succeeded on Etherscan. 
Afterwards, I still am able to send transactions to the contract. Can you tell me why? Doesn't `selfdestruct()` delete the contract code & storage from the network. Why it still accepts subsequent transaction requests? Help please...
Here the function:

```
function kill() public {
    selfdestruct(owner); 
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this explainer to align expectations with what it really does: https://blog.b9lab.com/selfdestruct-is-a-bug-9c312d1bb2a5

Answer (score 1):

`selfdestruct` *does* remove the code and storage from the network at that address, however it is still a valid address that can receive funds. There just happens to be no code there to handle the received funds.

Comment: that makes sense but when I call some functions on the contract, shouldn't it throw an error because there is no code left? I mean the interaction should be problematic right. It should not succeed.